# How to specify and interpret control variables in the model?

Tags: classification, interpretation

I'd like to build a classification model on customers across different countries, but not sure how to interpret the coefficient of those countries and other features, especially features that could be different by country, for example the shopping mall customers make their purchase. What are common best practice to include control variables like country but the same time also easy to interpret other variables? should i include interacted variable between country and each other feature?